# Why won't Stack Overflow allow me to participate without reputation points?

Tags: discussion

I've utilized this community for years to self-educate myself in various programming languages. In that time, I've never once needed to post a question. Somewhere in this vast forum, I've always found an answer or answers that can help me through whatever problem I'm facing. So much so that I didn't even register until recently. I aspire to stump veterans, not ask questions I can answer with thoughtful research and problem-solving.

That said, I'm now at a level where I'm noticing answers that don't really answer questions despite being technically accurate. Alternatively, there are simple questions that go poorly answered if they're answered at all. Yet, I don't have the reputation to vote, comment, or answer any of it.

How does one obtain reputation if they don't ask questions?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from answering questions.  Though if you are considering posting to answered questions, it wont get you as much as answering fresh questions.

Answer (score 12):

This is described in [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Since you don't have a question to post (yet), I recommend you to start answering some answers or editing posts. You will become in better shape once you start doing this.

Some suggestions:

- In order to search questions to answer, you may start filtering the questions by a tag of your personal taste. For example, I like to answers questions tagged by [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). You may choose this tag or another of your personal preference.
- You may mark a tag as favorite by hovering the mouse over a tag, then a popup message will appear with a *short* description of the tag, and there will be a star at the top left corner, mark the star and the tag will appear on the right part, so you can search questions that have this tag easier.
- When editing posts, make sure your edit improves the understanding of the question. This may be:

  - Indenting code
  - Clarifying the content of the post
  - Adding/removing relevant tags to the question
  - Moving explanations given by OP (Original Poster) in comments to the question.
- When editing posts, make sure to also (not just) remove any *Hello*, *Thanks*, *Regards*, *Here's my cool signature* and similar noise from question.
- When editing posts, make sure you're fixing all the issues you find. Since you have < 2k rep, your edits will be marked as suggestions and will be pending to approval. Also, since you edit a post, this will block other users from editing it unless your edit is approved or rejected.
- Any action you do on the site, do it thinking on the benefit of the community, not on earning rep.

Comment: Ditto the "do it for the community, not for points", though the way things are structured here, you need *some* points to affect the community. But the longest journey etc etc.

Comment: Thank you Luiggi, Ben, and Plutonix. Your responses definitely help clarify things.

The rep points are really secondary to the main concern: how to gain full participation rights in the community?

I'll focus on your suggestions while answering questions rather than asking them (for now).

Thanks again,
A

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way to get reputation is to *answer* questions. Giving back to the community is great!

And you only need 1 upvote to be able to upvote, 5 to be able to comment, and 13 to be able to downvote.